# Мультиязычность Yii2 проблема

Tags: yii2, интернационализация

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема: не переводит слова с русского на английский и обратно.

Код конфигурации:

```
$config = [
        ...
         'components' => [
                ...
                'i18n' => [
                   'translations' => [
                         'labels' => [
                            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                            'basePath'=>'app\translations',
                            'sourceLanguage'=>'en'
                            ],
                          ],
                       ],
                 ...
               ],
           ];
```

Файлы в 'app\translations':

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код labels, что для ru,:

```
<?php

   return[

   'lang_en'=>'lang_ru',
   'en'=>'ru',
   'I am line'=>'Я линия'];
```

Код labels, что для en,:

```
   <?php

       return[

       'lang_ru'=>'lang_en',
       'ru'=>'en',
       'Я линия'=>'I am line'];
```

Код для вью:

```
    <?php

       echo \Yii::t('labels', 'I am line');
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
$config = [
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Не помогло. Хм. В чем ещё может быть проблема? Остальное ничего не трогал, все стоит по дефолту.